# Обработка события нажатия правого клика мыши по кнопке

Tags: c++, winapi

Только недавно начал разбираться с WinApi, и в процессе решения лабораторной возник вопрос: как обработать нажатие правой кнопки мыши по отдельно взятой кнопки окна? Событие WM_RBUTTONDOWN определяет нажатие правой кнопки мыши по всему окну, поэтому оно мне не подходит. Если не затруднит, можете предоставить пример кода, а то я только начинающий. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, подобный подход (использование правой кнопки мыши на кнопке) является плохой практикой в разработке GUI, так как нарушает ожидаемое пользователем поведение кнопки.

Если кнопка подразумевает дополнительный набор связанных с ней действий, используйте кнопку с маленькой кнопочкой-стрелкой на её правой стороне (такие имеют оконный класс `BS_SPLITBUTTON`, либо `BS_DEFSPLITBUTTON`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же вам по какой-то причине нужна обработка именно правой кнопки мыши (и я очень надеюсь, что это учебное задание, а не реальная разработка), то единственный способ пойти против рекомендаций Microsoft — перехватывать («сабклассить») нужное вам оконное сообщение `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <cstring>

// Указатель на исходный обработчик кнопки
WNDPROC oldButtonProc;

// Обработчик нажатия правой кнопки мыши
// Замечание: bDblCkick всегда равен FALSE
static void onRButtonClick(HWND hwnd, BOOL bDblClick, int x, int y, UINT uKey)
{
    // ...
}

// Перехватчик
static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Обрабатываем WM_RBUTTONDOWN, а остальное передаём обработчику кнопки по умолчанию
    // Для удобства воспользуемся message crackers из <windowsx.h>
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, onRButtonClick);

        default:
            return oldButtonProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

// Где-то в коде надо назначить наш обработчик нужной кнопке следующим образом
// (для удобства оформил всё в отдельную функцию. hButtonWnd — hwnd нужной кнопки):
void subclassButton(HWND hButtonWnd)
{
    // Преобразуем типы без нарушения strict aliasing rule
    const WNDPROC newProc = WindowProc;
    LONG_PTR newValue;
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    static_assert(sizeof(newValue) == sizeof(newProc), "incompatible conversion");
#endif
    memcpy(&newValue, &newProc, sizeof(newProc));

    const LONG_PTR oldValue = SetWindowLongPtr(hButtonWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, newValue);

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    static_assert(sizeof(oldButtonProc) == sizeof(oldValue), "incompatible conversion");
#endif
    memcpy(&oldButtonProc, &oldValue, sizeof(oldValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для обычных кнопок следует использовать уведомление BN_CLICKED, пример в похожем вопросе на SO: [winapi BN_CLICKED how to identify which button was clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640330/winapi-bn-clicked-how-to-identify-which-button-was-clicked)

Comment: По приведённой вами ссылки идёт речь о различении кнопок-элементов управления. Здесь же вопрос про различение кнопок мыши.

Answer (score 0):

Большущие спасибо пользователю Arhad за помощь в решении данной проблемы.
Но я сделал чуть-чуть по-другому. Оставлю код для таких же деревянных, как и я.

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#define ID_BUT 100


LRESULT APIENTRY WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT APIENTRY SubclassProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
static void onRButtonClick(HWND hWnd, BOOL bDblClick, int x, int y, UINT uKey);
static void onLButtonClick(HWND hWnd, BOOL bDblClick, int x, int y, UINT uKey);




int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

{
    HWND hMainWnd;

    TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("MyClass");
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Cannot register class"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hMainWnd = CreateWindow(szClassName, TEXT("A Hello1 Application"), WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0, 0, 860, 380, (HWND)NULL, (HMENU)NULL, (HINSTANCE)hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

WNDPROC OldButtonProc;

static void onRButtonClick(HWND hWnd, BOOL bDblClick, int x, int y, UINT uKey)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("R_CLICK"), TEXT("MessageBox"), MB_OK);

}

static void onLButtonClick(HWND hWnd, BOOL bDblClick, int x, int y, UINT uKey)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("L_CLICK"), TEXT("MessageBox"), MB_OK);

}
LRESULT APIENTRY WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hBut;

    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:

        hBut = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 170, 60, 60, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BUT, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
        OldButtonProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(hBut, GWLP_WNDPROC);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hBut, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)SubclassProc);
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        SetWindowLongPtr(hBut, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)OldButtonProc);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT APIENTRY SubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, onRButtonClick);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, onLButtonClick);
    }
    return CallWindowProc(OldButtonProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arhad написал:

> Если же вам по какой-то причине нужна обработка именно правой кнопки мыши (и я очень надеюсь, что это учебное задание, а не реальная разработка), то единственный способ пойти против рекомендаций Microsoft — перехватывать («сабклассить») нужное вам оконное сообщение WM_RBUTTONDOWN

Это не единственный способ. Мне не понятно, зачем автору вопроса нужен именно правый клик на кнопке, обычно он используется для обработки контекстного меню. Если так, то этот способ логичнее и проще:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    ...
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Test"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 150, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)12345, hInst, nullptr);
        break;
    case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
        if (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)wParam) == 12345) {
            POINT pt = {(short)LOWORD(lParam), (short)HIWORD(lParam)};
            if ((pt.x != -1) || (pt.y != -1)) {
                TCHAR buffer[1024];
                ScreenToClient((HWND)wParam, &pt);
                _stprintf(buffer, TEXT("at %i, %i"), pt.x, pt.y);
                MessageBox(hWnd, buffer, TEXT("RBUTTON Click"), 0);
            }
        }
        break;
    ...
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Кнопка 12345 используется только для примера, аналогично работает любая другая кнопка или окно. Проверка координат здесь сделана только чтобы отклонить срабатывания на `menu key`.